# Dynamic Routes Identified by a Symbol in Vuejs / Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxtjs for an app. There are many routes leading to different pages/sections of the site.

However, for one particular type of route, I would like it to be identified by a symbol.

For example, a normal route can be created to a user profile page, as follows:

www.mywebsite.com/user/username

However, what if I want my route to look like this:

www.mywebsite.com/@username

How do I setup something like this in Nuxt or Vue?